# Getting duplicate resource error in gradle android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

I m adding google maps and firebase messaging in my android app but after building the error as duplicate resource.

**My log cat error is**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> [string/google_api_key] F:\Android Workspace\FoxindTracker\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml    [string/google_api_key] F:\Android Workspace\FoxindTracker\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

**My compile dependency are as follows**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.+'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.+'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.4'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.4'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.4'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
//    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0'
    compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    }
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.10.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:+"
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help me where am i wrong

Comment: Hi Mohit. So how do you solve this problem?

Comment: I had declared same resource id twice.  I removed the extra resource. That's it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mohit. Solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest to check your **string.xml** have duplicate or same string you have decalred double.  So you can check once your all string resources

As per your log error

> google_api_key

Is duplicate String. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 5):

Just rename google_api_key to something like g_api_key. Firebase name it as google_api_key so it shows duplicate. I hope this helps.